# What will be the product when 3,4-dibromocyclohexene is reacted with sodium followed by heating with selenium?

Tags: organic-chemistry, elimination

I'm tutoring few Class 12 students for their chemistry exams. I'm stuck with few problems. I don't know, if the key is wrong or I am wrong.

> [image]

According to me product (A) must be the cyclic diene, as given in option (A). Now, I don't know, what happens when you heat cyclic diene with selenium. But I do know that,  $\ce{SeO2}$  oxidizes allylic positions of alkenes into alcohols. But, none of the options given are fitting into that argument.

The answer given in the book is option (B).
How can that be explained?

Comment: Some pre-aromatic hydrocarbons can be easily oxidized by sulfur or similar rather weak oxidants into aromatic hydrocarbons. It is different type of reactions and it is not general

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming your Product A is correct then product B should be benzene. Selenium act as a mild oxidizing agent at temperature 220 °C to 330 °C. In the above reaction selenium oxidizes cyclohexadiene to form benzene.

Below is a reaction in which 1-methyl-1,3-cyclohexadiene is converted into toluene.
[image]

you can also go to this [link for more info](http://www.chemgapedia.de/vsengine/vlu/vsc/en/ch/2/vlu/oxidation_reduktion/aroma_ringe.vlu/Page/vsc/en/ch/2/oc/reaktionen/formale_systematik/oxidation_reduktion/oxidation/entfernen_wasserstoff/aromatisierung_6_ringe.vscml.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since the treatment of your compound with sodium will result the formation of diene as both bromine elements have same affinity to remove otherwise as per wurtz reaction sodium generates alkyl compound . The diene here forms benzene as the se acts as the oxidizing agent As per the options available the answer is benzene